# google search html doesn't contain div id='resultStats'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get the number of search results of a google search, which looks like this in the html, if i just save it from the browser:

```html
<div id="resultStats">About 8,660,000,000 results<nobr> (0.49 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

But the HTML retrieved by python looks like a mobile website when I open it in a browser and it doesn't contain 'resultStats'.

I already tried (1) adding parameters to the URL like `https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=test` and (2) copying a complete URL from a browser, but it didn't help.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def google_results(query):
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', id='resultStats')
    return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', div.text.split()[1])))

print(google_results('test'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback: line 11, in google_results
    return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', div.text.split()[1])))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: You need to add a `User-Agent` header to the request, to masquerade as a standard browser.

Comment: I think there is no `div` tag with the id of `resultStats`. So it returns `None`value for `div` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add headers (Thanks, John):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def google_results(query):
    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0'
    }
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', id='resultStats')
    return int(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', div.text.split()[1])))

print(google_results('test'))
```

Output:

```
9280000000
```