# How to fetch the total number of results from a google search in the News section

Tags: python-3.x, google-news

Is there a way to use python GoogleNews library to extract the **total number of results** for a specific search from the "News" section.
For example, if we google search "iPhone 14 pro max" and click on the "News" section, we can see the (total) number of results displayed (pic below) "About 11,200,000 results"

[image]

(By the way, I have already tried several posted solutions but none worked for me)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since this answers your question, I've voted to close yours as a duplicate [google search html doesn't contain div id='resultStats'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019565/google-search-html-doesnt-contain-div-id-resultstats)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and digging I found the solution in one of the postings

[google search html doesn't contain div id='resultStats'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019565/google-search-html-doesnt-contain-div-id-resultstats)

If you follow the answer of that post you will be able to retrieve the number of records returned from any google search. Just modify the "query" value and you are all set.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. If your question is answered by that one, you should close yours as a duplicate